# Can I modify a ciphertext created in AES with OFB mode?

Tags: encryption, attacks, aes

Suppose a service uses AES to encrypt Cookies, of the form

```
user=username+padding,tmstmp=timestamp
```

where `tmstmp` is the expiration time and `+padding` is a series of zeroes to make the total length be a multiple of 16 bytes.

If they create their admin cookie by just using `admin` as the username, like

```
user=admin000000,tmstmp=timestamp
```

Is their any conceivable way to take an encrypted cookie for a normal cookie, i.e.

```
AES(user=joesixpack0000,tmstmp=timestamp)
```

and turn it into an `admin` cookie, without knowing the Key or IV used in the encryption?

Comment: No, you need the key

Comment: But won't I know that the first 5 cipher text characters are the encrypted version of `user=`? Can't I make changes with that knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are discussing is called a [known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack):

> The known-plaintext attack (KPA) is an attack model for cryptanalysis
>   where the attacker has access to both the plaintext (called a crib),
>   and its encrypted version (ciphertext). These can be used to reveal
>   further secret information such as secret keys and code books.

But

> Modern ciphers such as Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) are not currently
>   known to be susceptible to known-plaintext attacks.

While you may find this inconvenient, it is important for the security of our digital world. Consider the fact that HTTP messages frequently start with predictable sequences of text ([HTTP reference](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_HTTPRequestMessageFormat.htm)). So the start of an HTTPS message is somewhat predictable. This is true for many other types of encrypted data. If someone could guess the plaintext and then be able to decrypt or modify the message, the situation would be rather dire.